# WCF Custom binding - send timeout always reached

Tags: wcf, binding, wcf-security

I have a wcf service that needs to implement callbacks and be hosted on IIS 6.0. Since IIS 6.0 doesn't support the net.tcp binding, I decided to use a custom binding because the service is accessed by different clients in different timezones and, using custom binding, I can set the allowed clock skew time to values other than the default one.

Here is my server config file:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>        
    <binding name="pscNetBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00">          
      <reliableSession acknowledgementInterval="00:00:00.2000000"
  flowControlEnabled="true" inactivityTimeout="23:59:59"
  maxPendingChannels="128" maxRetryCount="8" maxTransferWindowSize="128"
  ordered="true" />
      <compositeDuplex />
      <oneWay maxAcceptedChannels="128" packetRoutable="false">
        <channelPoolSettings idleTimeout="00:10:00"
  leaseTimeout="00:10:00" maxOutboundChannelsPerEndpoint="10" />
      </oneWay>
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
  messageVersion="Default" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
  maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false"
  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
  allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
  keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
  proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered"
  unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="SchneiderElectric.PSCNet.Server.Services.PSCNetWCFService" behaviorConfiguration="Behaviors1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress ="http://10.155.18.18:2000/PSCNet"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="pscNetBinding"
                                contract="SchneiderElectric.PSCNet.Server.Contracts.IPSCNetWCFService"/>
  </service>
</services>    
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Behaviors1">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled = "true"/>
      <!--<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2048" maxConcurrentSessions="2048" maxConcurrentInstances="2048" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />-->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client config file:

```
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="pscNetBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00">            
        <reliableSession acknowledgementInterval="00:00:00.2000000"
    flowControlEnabled="true" inactivityTimeout="23:59:59"
    maxPendingChannels="128" maxRetryCount="8" maxTransferWindowSize="128"
    ordered="true" />
        <compositeDuplex />
        <oneWay maxAcceptedChannels="128" packetRoutable="false">
          <channelPoolSettings idleTimeout="00:10:00"
    leaseTimeout="00:10:00" maxOutboundChannelsPerEndpoint="10" />
        </oneWay>
        <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
    messageVersion="Default" writeEncoding="utf-8" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </textMessageEncoding >
        <httpTransport manualAddressing="false"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
    proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered"
    unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />                    
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://10.155.18.18:2000/PSCNet" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="pscNetBinding" contract="PSCNetWCFService.IPSCNetWCFService"
        name="pscNetBinding" />
  </client>
```

If I use the server and client on the same machine, everything works fine. If I run them on different machines, I get the following error:

> Could not connect to
>   http://10.155.18.198:9000/e60ba5b3-f979-4922-b9f8-c820caaa04c2. TCP
>   error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   10.155.18.198:9000.

Can anyone in the community help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the part of the config where you're defining the customBinding?  Maybe you just didn't paste that part in, but when you define a custom binding, you have to specify an encoding and a transport at minimum - something like this:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyCustomTextTcpBinding">
            <textMessageEncoding />
            <tcpTransport />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Can you also paste in the part where you're defining your "pscNetBinding" bindingConfiguration?

Comment: Thanks for the response i had changed my binding to net.tcp binding and everything works well. I am planning to host it on widnows service. Do you think is it good to host on windows service provided that my service is only used for login validation and Autocad generation at the servce.

Comment: Yeah, I would think a windows service would be fine.  If you have IIS 6.0, you can't really host a nettcp service anyway.  In IIS 7, you can host nettcp using WAS, but if it was me, I'd just do a windows service.  Here's a good article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the article, i just wanted to be sure that what i am doing is right by hosting on windows service. Since it is deployed in production server, do you see any disadvantage in using windows service ?

Comment: We host of a lot of our WCF services as Windows Services.  It's been working fine for us, especially for non-HTTP services.

Answer (score -1):

Windows service is undoubtely a nice solution but i think a better would be a self hosting
and you could have anytype of binding on it.